# How to install Tridion Databases in Microsoft Azure SQL

Tags: web8.5, sdl-tridion, installation, azure, azuresql

I am trying to install SDL Web 8.5 in Microsoft Azure, for which I am planning to host all Tridion DB's in Microsoft Azure SQL Database. As far as I know we used to run  PowerShell commands to install it on Microsoft SQL Servers like `.\Install Content Manager database.ps1` , but how can I run these commands for Azure SQL DB or what actually needs to be done to create Tridion databases in Azure SQL ?

if i create Tridion DB's in Azure, how would Tridion Application (CME) interact them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You install the databases the same way you would do with a "regular" SQL Server, only this time the server address is of the Azure SQL, for example:
`& '.\Install Content Manager database.ps1' -DatabaseServer someAddress.database.windows.net -DatabaseName ...`

As far as Tridion (CME) is concerned it will work the exact same way. The same goes for all the storage configurations of the CD roles.

Comment: Thanks @atila sos for your comments. does it mean i need to run the commands on my my azure virtual Machine, which has Microsoft Sql Server installed ? if this is the case, then Tridion Db's are still in Sql server only but in azure. (Not in standalone Microsoft Azure SQL db)

Comment: Whether you have an Azure VM with SQL Server installed, or you use Azure SQL (as a service) it makes no difference, you just supply the address of the server and other relevant details to the installation script.